# UISearchBar with hidden UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have the search bar in the top of the table and the hidden navigation bar. Along with **UISearchBar** I use **UISearchDisplayController**. **UISearchDisplayController** has the possibility to bring forward the navigation bar. So, when I tap the cancel button in the search bar, the navigation bar fly's down. How can I dismiss this possibility, so the navigation bar will always be hidden?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnaly!!!! I've found the solution [IPHONE: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController hidden navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117095/iphone-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-hidden-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make the search bar the table header view in which case it will scroll with the table, and if you don't want it to appear by default then you can programmatically scroll the table down, non-animated, in viewWillAppear it is first displayed. This may or may not make sense for your UI design, but it is, for example, how Safari basically works.

Comment: Hi Nimrod. Thanks for reply. But the problem not in the searchbar but in navigationbar. To see what I talked about you can run the Mail application on your iPhone, and tap on searchbar. You will see that the navigationbar fly's in and fly's out. What I need is to dismiss  this function