# UINavigationbar will show after UISearchbar end search,how can i hide the navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

My app hide the navigationbar in the beginning.

But in a view(full screen), there is a search bar.

when I begin to search, the search bar stays in the top of the view.

Then I cancel the search,change the search bar's frame,the navigationbar appears.

Why does this happen?  how can I hide the navigation bar ?

I tried this:

I add some logs in searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch and `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` to show navigtaionbar status.

> In searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch, navigationController.navigationBarHidden is YES,
>
> In searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch, navigationController.navigationBarHidden is NO.

Then I set `navigationController.navigationBarHidden to YES` in `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`,The navigation bar will show but hide in a short time,and navigation bar will never show again.(`navigationController.navigationBarHidden` will always be YES)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a similar question here: [UISearchBar with hidden UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127013/uisearchbar-with-hidden-uinavigationbar)

And the solution: [IPHONE: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController hidden navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117095/iphone-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-hidden-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in ViewDidLoad Method.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES
```

Other Wise

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden =YES;
```

Comment: I set self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden to YES in searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch, it works.But at first time, the navigation bar will show first, then hide immediately，seems too weird.Is there any way to hide navigation bar and user won't see it.

Answer (score -1):

- you can use the following code in your `viewDidLoad` to hide the navigation bar `Self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;`
- if you are presenting the navigation controller then  you can hide your navigationbar before presenting, by using this code `yournavigation.navigaionBar.hidden = YES;`
- we can use either of the code to hide navigation bar `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

  or

  `Self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;`
- **Final one it may solve your problem** hide navigation bar in `viewWillAppear`. Here i am adding code

  `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  }`

Comment: You should never use navigationController.navigationBar.hidden - use navigationController.navigationBarHidden

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.If I use navigationController.navigationBar.hidden,and set to YES,there will be a black space in the top,seems the navigationbar still use this space.

Comment: @Simon Hi Simon but just now i checked both codes both are working fine nd if is there any reason to do not use navigationController.navigationBar.hidden , can you please explain little more?

Comment: The UINavigationController controls the navigation bar.  If you use navigationController.navigationBar.hidden then at a later point the navigation controller will show or hide it to match what it wants; whereas if you use navigationController.navigationBarHidden then the controller will show or hide it according to what you want.

Comment: @simon  Okay thanks for your information and I modified my answer also.